# CSS-How to center a page without adding margin?

Tags: html, css, sharepoint-2013, centering

We have a web page generated via SharePoint 2013 that has a width of 1024. We use the following style on the main content div:

```
#container_master {
    width:1024px !important;
    margin-left: auto !important;
    margin-right: auto !important;  
    background-color:#FFF !important;
}
```

This works well on resolutions *greater than* 1024.  Whenever someone sets their resolution to 1024 (which we have a couple of folks that do that), there is some extra padding on the left and right sides which bring about the horizontal scroll bar.

Whenever I use FireBug, I see the following HTML being generated:

```
<div aria-relevant="all" aria-live="polite" style="margin-left: 20px; margin-right: 20px; min-width: 1024px;">
```

This margin of 20px on the left and right is the problem.  I found that it can be removed by adding the following CSS:

```
html body.ms-backgroundImage form#aspnetForm div#s4-workspace.ms-core-overlay div#s4-bodyContainer div#contentRow div {
    margin-left: 0px !important;
    margin-right: 0px !important;
}
```

However, whenever I do this, the page is no longer centered on screen sizes greater than 1024.  Any ideas on how to make the page "full screen" for those using 1024 resolution while making it centered for those with greater resolutions?

Comment: what about margin:0 auto!important; ?

Comment: Seems to me that your horizontal scrolling is caused by the hard coded width, not your margins.  You should really reevaluate your use of `!important`.

Comment: Please, please, please! You are **massively** overusing !important`. There needs to be a **very** good reason to use it and this does **not** seam to be one of those reasons.

Answer (score 0):

There's a nice trick for this in CSS.

use:

```
html body.ms-backgroundImage form#aspnetForm div#s4-workspace.ms-core-overlay div#s4-bodyContainer div#contentRow div {
  margin-left: 0 auto !important;
  margin-right: 0 auto !important;
}
```

This is the same as:

```
html{ margin: 0px; margin: auto; }
```

Sometimes IE won't use margin: auto; To solve this (in some way) add:

```
body {
  text-align: center;
 }
```

But this only happens with old IE browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Use `max-width`:

```
#container_master {
    max-width:1024px !important;
    margin-left: auto !important;
    margin-right: auto !important;  
    background-color:#FFF !important;
}
```

Comment: This won't work because margins and padding aren't included in the width property.

Comment: @KeesSonnema How do you figure this won't work?  The right/left margins are set to auto, which equates to 0 if the element is as wide as its parent element.

Comment: Sorry I've read this wrong. I thought you only changed the width to max-width, but you also changed the margins. Nevermind :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the width property with max-width and reset the min-width:

http://jsfiddle.net/ht2Gc/

```
div {
  max-width: 1024px !important; /* here */
  margin-left: auto !important;
  margin-right: auto !important;  
  background-color: #FFF !important;
  min-width: 0 !important; /* and here */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**A lot of screens have a width of 1024px. for smaller screens the horizontal scrollbar isn't avoidable when you want to have a specific width of your webpage/web application (you might want to consider using *min-width* and *max-width*). Unless you are designing your website for a specific browser such as chrome I would advise to make your webpage about 4px smaller. Most web browsers have small borders on the sides, which means a 1024px screen loses a few pixels for your display. Please consider the things said above.

*You can probably solve your particular problem with the following css line*

```
body{margin:0;padding:0}
```

What happens here is that you tell the body to have no padding, which means your website has no extra margin on the sides.

*this should solve your problem with the margin. If the scrollbar still appears while you dont want it, then also add these lines to your css:*

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 1020px) and (max-device-width: 1030px){
    body{overflow:hidden}
}
```

This checks whether the window size is within certain limits (**in this case between 1020px and 1030px**), if that is the case, the body will disregard everything that is bigger than the window, thus disabling the scrollbar.